# Multiple Insert Queries are not working with TSQLQuery with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, delphi

I am working on one issue where I need to `insert` multiple records using `TSQLQuery` at once in my `Mysql` Database.

Below is Testing code:

```
    var
  LSQLQuery : TSQLQuery;
begin
  LSQLQuery:=TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    LSQLQuery.SQLConnection:=SQLConnection1;
    LSQLQuery.SQL.Add('Insert into TestTable(P_ID, F_Name, L_Name) values (2,"Vijay", "Chauhan");');
    LSQLQuery.SQL.Add('Insert into TestTable(P_ID, F_Name, L_Name) values (4,"raj", "Chauhan");');
    LSQLQuery.SQL.Add('Insert into TestTable(P_ID, F_Name, L_Name) values (5,"XXX", "Chauhan");');
    LSQLQuery.ExecSQL;//Execute the query
      finally
        LSQLQuery.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

I dont know whats wrong I am doing but everytime I execute this I get the error as follows:

**---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------**

**Project Test.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Insert into TestTable(P_ID, F_Name, L_Name) values (2,'Vijay', 'Chauhan');
insert into Te' at line 2'.**

Can anyone help me to get it done?
I am not sure where I am wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to terminate each statement with `;`, including the final one. This is standard SQL behavior. Voting to close as a simple typo/non-reproduceable error.

Comment: I tried with the same also but no luck

Comment: no need to repeat the statement, just append values: `Insert into TestTable(P_ID, F_Name, L_Name) values (2,"Vijay", "Chauhan"),  (4,"raj", "Chauhan"), (5,"XXX", "Chauhan")`

Comment: You also have embedded double-quotes, which should be single. You really should find a basic SQL tutorial. Also, stop concatenating SQL and use parameters, which removes the issue of quotes and data conversions entirely, as the database driver will do that for you.

Comment: @whosrdaddy Thanks for the help.
I was doing wrong by assigning the values to `commatext` of `SQLQuery.SQL` which was giving me error.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I have one Question that how many records we can add like comma separated records in single insert Query for `MySQL`.

Comment: Depends on the size of the query, check  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';` on your MySQL server...

Comment: Thank you @whosrdaddy. It helps me alot